# Markdown for Image resizing not working as recommanded

Tags: markdown

This little example mentioned many times for propper markdown to rzise images

```
![Kitten](/media/kitten.jpg){ width=50% }
```

However it does not rezise the image and shows what is in the curly braces

[image]

as in here. Any hint how to propper format markdown

Comment: which environment are you using, markdown in RStudio, GitHub...?

Comment: did it in VSCode,Jupyterlab and with pelican

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The markdown syntax stated in your question happens to work only for specific flavours of markdown.

I tested it OK in R Markdown / R Pandoc. However, it does not work in JupyterLab or VS Code.

What does work there is:

```
<div><img src="https://www.nasa.gov/images/content/365640main_PIA11141_full.jpg" width="50%"/></div>
```

I just tested it OK in a JupyterLab markdown cell.

Comment: thanks for that I was hopping for some common solution...but yes that does work